# How do I format a number to have a fixed precision AND a fixed number of integral digits?

Tags: php

I want to print out a decimal number with the following rules:

- There should always be two digits to the left of the decimal point.
- There should always be three digits to the right of the decimal point.

So here are some examples of how I want numbers to be displayed:

- 12.345
- 02.310
- 07.499
- 42.300

I recognize that I could use modulo arithmetic to separate the integral and decimal parts, then format them separately, but that seems messy. I'm hoping there's a simpler solution using `sprintf`, though I can't seem to get it to work.

I've already tried the following (none of which work):

```
printf('%02.3f', 2.31); // nope
printf('%5.3f', 2.31);  // nadda
printf('%05.5f', 2.31); // no way
printf('%02d', 2.31);   // obviously not
printf('%03f', 2.31);   // not that either
```

Is there no clean way to do this? Can I not have my cake (leading zeros) and eat it too (fixed decimal precision at the same time)?

Comment: which version of PHP you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
echo sprintf("%06.3f", 2.31);
```

Output:

```
02.310
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.  Some explanation would be a bonus too.